# Cordova Accelerometer Plugin Watch Acceleration Issue

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugins

I've been experimenting with Cordova's Accelerometer Plugin and have an issue that so far I've been unable to fix on Android. `motionID` is used within the `clearWatch` method to halt `watchAcceleration`.

More info can be found here [cordova-plugin-device-motion docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-device-motion)

```
var motionID = null;


function startAccelerometer() {
var refreshRate = {
    frequency: 50
};
motionID = navigator.accelerometer.watchAcceleration(
    gotMotion, onMotionError, refreshRate);
}
```

Then using the `clearWatch()` function to stop it I call

```
function stopAcclererometer() {

navigator.accelerometer.clearWatch(motionID);
$("#acclData").empty();
}
```

The problem seem to be that `clearWatch` does not clear the motionID if `startAccelerometer()` is called more than once, or if a new `motionID` is created without first clearing it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a fairly simple fix but I'm still wondering if there may be a cleaner way to solve the problem. I managed to get around it by attaching a simple count into the mix and exiting if a condition has been reached i.e. Start was pressed and then clearing the count when Stopped.

```
if (count > 0) {
        return;
    } else if (count === 0) {
        startAccelerometer();
    }
});
```